# Does anybody know why I get different results when using IE7 mode in IE10 to IE7 mode in IE11?

Tags: internet-explorer

```
My setup:
Windows 7
IE 11 in IE7 mode

page does not display as it should


Another setup:
Windows 8
IE 10 in IE7 mode

page does display as it should
```

Does anybody know whether this is any of the following:

- win 8 more reliable emulation
- ie 10 more reliable emulation
- win 7 more reliable emulation
- ie 11 more reliable emulation
- any combination of the above

Comment: IE is always a fuddu browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those browser modes are there to give you an *indication* but are not exactly the same as the real IE7. If you want to know the exact result download the virtual machines from Microsoft: https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads

Comment: An hour and a half to download the ie7 VM, but now I know that it is ie10 emulation of ie7 that is useless.  The ie11 emulation was spot on, which is a shame because now I have to fix it to work in IE7 :-(

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because many of our css properties are deprecated in higher versions of IE. So, it looks different using different versions of IE. 
My suggestion is to look those css properties and alter those by the valid (non-deprecated) ones.

Comment: that's a good possibility - gonna take me forever to pin down though :-)